# General multiplication in numpy for scalars and arrays possible?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

For a general code that should be able to take scalars and arrays, I would like "@" to work with scalars, e.g.

```
a = 4
b = 3
```

as well as for arrays

```
a = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]])
b = np.array([1, 2])
```

The goal would that I can use for both cases

```
a@b
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

**Update 2021-06-17**

@hpaulj thanks for the response.

I updated above to hopefully clarify.  Currently I have a if-query to check if scalar or array and separate calculations with * and @, respectively.  I was thinking it would simplify things if there was just one operation.

Maybe a stupid follow up:
Would it make sense to extend @/np.matmul to be able to do the scalar multiplication?  Or is there a reason that would make this a bad idea?

Comment: `*` works with scalars.  `np.dot` is also ok.. Read `np.matmul` docs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like numpy.dot is the most general code available for multiplications.

@ is numpy.matmult and not numpy.dot, which are indeed not the same (see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html):

> matmul differs from dot in two important ways:
>
> ```
> Multiplication by scalars is not allowed, use * instead.
>
> Stacks of matrices are broadcast together as if the matrices were elements, respecting the signature (n,k),(k,m)->(n,m):
> ```

I still have to see the consequence of this aspect for my code.

Here is a simple code to show what is going on:

```
import numpy as np

# with matrix (only up to 2D)
a = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.matrix([[5, 6]]).T

c1 = a*b
c2 = a@b
c3 = np.dot(a, b)

# with array (general)
A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
B = np.array([[5, 6]]).T

C1 = A*B
C2 = A@B
C3 = np.dot(A, B)

# scalar
aS = 2
bS = 3

cS1 = aS*bS
#cS2 = aS@bS # does not work
cS3 = np.dot(aS, bS)
```